# OpenCV won't find Prime Sense and OpenNI

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, kinect, openni

I have experience using Kinect in Windows and Visual Studio. But I want to use functions from OpenCV in Linux and did the following:

Installed OpenNI (old 1.5 version from github)
Installed Nite (1.5)
Installed SensorKinect (from git)

After that, I could run the OpenNI samples normally.

Now I want to use OpenCV, which I already had installed but not configured to work with Kinect. I went to the opencv source folder and tried to cmake it again with the WITH_OPENNI flag, but it can't find openni neither the prime sense.

I think maybe libs and bins from both aren't in the right place, but I don't know how to check where they are or how to point the path to cmake. What should I do? I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Did you use ccmake or similar to set the paths for OpenNI and PrimeSense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

to find openni folder

```
locate XnOS.h
```

and it should give something like

```
/usr/include/ni/XnOS.h
```

or

```
/usr/include/openni/XnOS.h
```

also some other directories like the source and so on... but the ones you care are /usr...
If you don't have this ones then the openni is not installed or not installed correctly

to tell the cmake the path I sugest you to use **ccmake** in the build directory

```
ccmake ..
```

This will give you the options and you may change variables and some paths....

Hope this helps you, if you still have trouble just post a comment